# gfortran makefile not working on mac

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, fortran90, gfortran

I am trying to run a makefile with gfortran in my mac. It compiles without problem in Fedora 18, but I can't make it work in Mac OS 10.8.4 with the last gfortran from HPC.
I am newbie on fortran, so some light would be appreciated.
Here is the Make file:

```
# Makefile made to work with GNU Make

.DEFAULT:

BIN=bin
OBJ=obj

vpath= %$(OBJ)/.o    $(OBJ)
vpath= %.mod  $(OBJ)

EXES= pasos   \
      pasosng \
      pasosm  \
      trans   \
      cost    \
      lcal    \
      fluj    \
      loc     \
      eval    \
      impas   \
      imptra  \
      mats    \
      imploc  \
      matesp  \
      dimen

FC=gfortran
LN=gfortran

FCFLAGS=$(USER_FCFLAGS) -g3 -B $(OBJ) -J $(OBJ) @fc_options @fc_warnings

LFLAGS=$(USER_LFLAGS)

ifdef SystemRoot
    dotexe=.exe
endif

ifdef F_PROFILE
    FCFLAGS:=$(FCFLAGS) -pg
    LFLAGS:=$(LFLAGS) -pg
endif

ifdef F_TEST
    FCFLAGS:=-O0 -fbounds-check $(FCFLAGS)
else
    FCFLAGS:=-O3 $(FCFLAGS)
endif

COMPILE=$(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< 
LINK=$(LN) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ -Wl,-Map=$@.map $^

%.o : %.f90
    $(COMPILE)

all: prepare $(EXES)
$(OBJ)/%.o : %.f90
    $(COMPILE)


clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ) $(BIN)

prepare: $(BIN) $(OBJ)

$(BIN):
    mkdir $(BIN)

$(OBJ):
    mkdir $(OBJ)


pasos: prepare $(BIN)/pasos$(dotexe)
    @echo $@

$(BIN)/pasos$(dotexe) : $(OBJ)/pasos.o \
        $(OBJ)/nodes.o  \
        $(OBJ)/io_list.o  \
        $(OBJ)/rcomm.o  \
        $(OBJ)/tparc.o  \
        $(OBJ)/zcomm.o  \
    $(OBJ)/rcomm.o \
    $(OBJ)/pcomm.o \
        $(OBJ)/getoptm.o  \
        $(OBJ)/control.o  \
        $(OBJ)/heap.o  \
        $(OBJ)/gener.o  \
        $(OBJ)/param.o  \
        $(OBJ)/ascii.o  \
        $(OBJ)/pcomm.o  \
    $(OBJ)/mensamod.o \
    $(OBJ)/optionsm.o \
        $(OBJ)/debugm.o 
    $(LINK)
```

The file is longer, but I dont know if it is needed to understand the error. The error I get when I run make over the directory is:

```
tcapelle$ gnumake
gfortran  -o bin/pasos -Wl,-Map=bin/pasos.map obj/pasos.o obj/nodes.o obj/io_list.o obj/rcomm.o obj/tparc.o obj/zcomm.o obj/pcomm.o obj/getoptm.o obj/control.o obj/heap.o obj/gener.o obj/param.o obj/ascii.o obj/mensamod.o obj/optionsm.o obj/debugm.o
            ld: unknown option: -Map=bin/pasos.map
            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        gnumake: *** [bin/pasos] Error 1
```

Edit: 
I changed in the makefile

```
LINK=$(LN) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ -Wl,-Map=$@.map $^
```

to

```
LINK=$(LN) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

and it compiles with some errors, but it worked.
What does this -Wl,-Map= thing do?

Comment: I think it has something to do with how to pass the arguments to the compiler and the folder struct in mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the BSD linker (in contrast to the GNU linker) does not recognize options, if they are separated from the corresponding value by an equal sign (instead of a whitespace). So

```
ld -Map test.map
```

is fine, while

```
ld -Map=test.map
```

is not. Therefore, you must make sure, the compiler passes the linker options to the linker in the latter form. For that you need

```
gfortran -Wl,-Map,test.map ...
```

which you can achieve by changing the definition of the `LINK` variable to:

```
LINK=$(LN) $(LFLAGS) -o $@ -Wl,-Map,$@.map $^
```

Comment: I get ld: unknown option: -Map
Is the -Map option a compiler option?

Comment: No, it is a linker option. Try `-map` with lower case, it seems that the option names of the linker had been somewhat changed in OSX compared to FreeBSD.